# Network security configuration

Tags: java, android, kotlin

What is the purpose of network security configuration , I know that http is not secure and when we want even to use that in our app we then use network security configuration but what does it really do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***First Network security is not all about securing one application. It's a platform which ensure the security of complete organization, platform, application. its a much broader term when we consider at enterprises level. However I just want to brief about it.***

It provides the below feature to any organization.

1. it detects and prevents the various attacks (ransomware or DDoS attack) or malicious activity using firewalls, IPS solutions.
2. it ensure the integrity on endpoints connected to an organization network or campuses to avoid any DDoS attack.
3. End to end data delivery of data between two sites over the internet in encrypted channel so no one can sniff the data and see what exactly in data.

When it comes to application level there are some application which we need to host direct to internet facing so users can access over the internet. However while doing so we need to be take care that our application is exposed to the world in that not all user are with good intention.

So, we have to be make sure our application should be secure and enabled with security features like SSL (secure socket layer) certificate or behind secure firewall devices and accessible over secure channel.

Basically, SSL certificate authentication requires three way handshake between Clients and server machine which basically exchange public and private key in certificate. This three way handshake only be succeed if client machine would he required private key combination to negotiate with server to access the contain.

Once the parameter are negotiated then three way channel would form between two machine further data transfer would take place after that.

All the above thing are to secure any organization data. Because data could contain sensitive information, or database information that would be critical to any environment. **In Today's era Data is Every thing.**